# Derivative of $L^\infty$ norm of a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. Under which assumptions does it make sense to compute $\frac{d}{dt}\Vert f(t,\cdot) \Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb R)}$ and what is it?

Comment: [Article on supremum norm differentiability](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume6_4/493956.pdf)

Comment: The $L^p$ norm $1 < p < \infty$ is differentiable.

Comment: @GEdgar What happens in the $\infty$ case?

Comment: @Jun $\sup$ norm may not be differentiable on $\mathbb R^2$. A fortiori the $\sup$ norm is not differentiable on a space of real function. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472376/differentiability-of-the-maximum-norm-on-mathbbr2).

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 3.1 of this [Supremum norm differentiability](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume6_4/493956.pdf) article provides necessary and sufficient conditions for the $\sup$ norm to be differentiable at a point of $\mathcal C(T,E)$ the space of continuous functions from the topological space $T$ to the Banach space $E$.

This is interesting and leverage the notion of smooth point.