# differentiablity of function of several variable

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $ 1<p< \infty $ and $ f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ ,  $ f(x)=(\sum_{j=1}^{n} |x_{j}|^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}} $  . At what point f is differentiable ?

I have thought that $ f $ is  not  differentiable  at  $0$  and  at  all  negative  points .  So  in  my  sense, $f$  is  differentiable  at  all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} , x>0 $ . But i am not sure. can anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144449/differentiability-of-norms may be of help to you.

Comment: what does $x>0$ mean when $x$ is a vector?